# ionic analytics event queue exceeded the quota

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, local-storage

I am experiencing an error in my application that is related to Ionic register user / deploy / analytics. This is the error that I get when running in the browser.

Uncaught QuotaExceededError: Failed to execute 'setItem' on 'Storage': Setting the value of 'ionic_analytics_event_queue_75549069' exceeded the quota.

If I comment out all the user / deploy / analytics code and remove the modules related, then the issue goes away.

It doesn't even load the first window. Blank white screen with that error in the console.

Ionic info: 
Cordova CLI: 5.3.3
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.0
Gulp local:
Ionic Version: 1.1.0
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.7
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.6.3
ios-deploy version: 1.7.0 
ios-sim version: 5.0.1 
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v0.12.7
Xcode version: Xcode 6.3.2 Build version 6D2105